# Running ng build in gulp uses older version of node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a gulp script for building angular files with `ng build`. It works if I run it from command prompt, but fails when I run it from gulp with error:

> You are running version v10.6.0 of Node.js, which is not supported by
>   Angular CLI 8.0+.The official Node.js version that is supported is
>   10.9 or greater.Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to update Node.js.Process terminated with code
>   0.C:***> cmd.exe /c gulp -b
>   "C:***"
>   --color --gulpfile "C:***\Gulpfile.js"
>   default

I have globally installed version of node v10.16.3, but it for some reason it says that I have `v10.6.0`. I am also using Gulp 4.

My gulp file looks like this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('buildNg', async function (cb) {
  exec('ng build', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
})
```

Does gulp use its own version of node.js? I don't see any other reason.

Comment: what is your output when you run `node -v` ?

Comment: @nijeeshjoshy When running from CMD I get 10.16, When running inside `exec` 10.6.

Comment: could you please try deleting your node_modules folder and run `npm install` after.

Comment: @nijeeshjoshy I've already tried deleting node_modules, clearing cache, restarting computers, reinstalling node.

Comment: try renaming your `package.json` file to `package.json.old` and  delete your node_modules folder and run npm install after

Comment: @nijeeshjoshy I dont think this is a problem with my packages

Comment: @FCin Have you tried:
`npm uninstall -g angular-cli` ->
 `npm cache verify` ->
`npm cache clean` ->
`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` ->
`npm cache verify` ?

Comment: Please run `where ng` `where node` and `where gulp` and add the output to your question

Answer (score 3):

In this message:

> You are running version v10.6.0 of Node.js, which is not supported by
>   Angular CLI 8.0+.The official Node.js version that is supported is
>   10.9 or greater.Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to update Node.js

The "v10.6.0" part is the output of `process.version` ([Source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular/cli/bin/ng))

So there is an old installation of Node.js somewhere on your drive. If you check the `PATH` environment variable, and the output of `where node` `where ng` and `where gulp`, you should be able to find it and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Install nvm (node version manager).

You can check installed versions:

`nvm list`

After that switch version:

`nvm use 10.16.3`

You need to run this command as administrator